# How to create drop down menu's in eclipse rcp according to alphabets dynamically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to create dropdown menu in eclipse rcp by alphabetical order, those dropdown menu's needs to be arranged according to alphabets.

Such that under main menu I want show alphabets. if there is any contribution related to alphabet then I have to create a dropdown menu under that alphabet.

```
// Use case
Menu
   A -> Action,
   B -> Bind,
   C -> Click
```

Please have a look into the attached use case diagram
[image]

Comment: Look at the `dynamic` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point - [see here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Populating_a_dynamic_submenu)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in e4, in the `Application.e4xmi` model, add to a `"Menu"` a `"Dynamic Menu Contribution"`
Link this dynamic menu to a class that will build the menu like this:

```
public class DynamicMenuContributor {
  @Inject
  private EModelService      modelService;
  @AboutToShow
  public void aboutToShow(List<MMenuElement> items) {

    for (String s  : <your collection of letters>) {
      MDirectMenuItem dynamicItem = modelService.createModelElement(MDirectMenuItem.class);
      dynamicItem.setLabel(s);
      dynamicItem.setContributorURI(<contributor uri>);
      dynamicItem.setContributionURI(<point the class that will handle the menu event>);
      // dynamicItem.setType(ItemType.RADIO);
      // dynamicItem.setSelected(selected);
      // dynamicItem.setIconURI(<url to icon>);
      // dynamicItem.getTransientData().put(<param1 name>, <param1 value>);
      // dynamicItem.getTransientData().put(<param2 name>, <param2value>);

      items.add(dynamicItem);
    }
  }
}
```

With a class to handle the event like this:

```
public class DynamicMenuSelectiontHandler {
  @Execute
  public void execute(MMenuItem menuItem) {
    <param1> =  menuItem.getTransientData().get(<param 1 name>);
    <param2> =  menuItem.getTransientData().get(<param 2 name>);
    <put your logic here>
  }
}
```